# Merging overlapping features using Geopandas?

Tags: overlapping-features, geopandas

I have a Shapefile with overlapping features.
Is there an easy way to merge them with geopandas?

I found a way with shapely, but I would like to do it with geopandas directly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The GeoDataFrame

```py
import geopandas as gpd
g1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file("poly_intersect.shp")
g1.shape
(4, 3)
```

[image]

[image]

1) You can use the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module

a) If you want to merge the intersections of the overlapping polygons

```py
import itertools
geoms = g1['geometry'].tolist()
intersection_iter = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gpd.GeoSeries([poly[0].intersection(poly[1]) for poly in  itertools.combinations(geoms, 2) if poly[0].intersects(poly[1])]), columns=['geometry'])
intersection_iter.to_file("intersection_iter.shp")
```

[image]

[image]

Union

```py
union_iter = intersection_iter.unary_union
```

b) If you want to merge the intersected polygons change `intersection` by `union` (all the polygons overlap in my example)

[image]

2) You can use [GeoPandas Overlay](http://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/set_operations.html?highlight=overlay#)

a)

```py
auto_inter = gpd.overlay(g1, g1, how='intersection')
auto_inter.shape
(7,4)
```

The resulting GeoDataframe

[image]

GeoPandas add the intersection geometries to the existing geometries, therefore

```py
intersection = auto_inter[4:7]
intersection.to_file("intersection.shp")
```

[image]

Union

```py
union = intersection.unary_union
```

b) use `gpd.overlay(g1, g1, how='union')`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to output a layer of distinct merged overlapping polygons, and not just a single multi-polygon, then after using:

```
union = intersection.unary_union
```

you can convert the resulting multi-poly to a GeoSeries:

```
shapes_series = gpd.GeoSeries([polygon for polygon in union])
```

or to a GeoDataFrame:

```
shapes_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame([polygon for polygon in union]).set_geometry(0)
```

Comment: This should probably be an edit to the first answer rather than an answer in it's own right

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'd end up reworking gene's answer, and it's not worth the effort. I couldn't add a comment either as my rep is below 50.