# Merge overlapping polygons based on attribute

Tags: geopandas, shapely

My objective is very similar to these questions: [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/334459/how-to-dissolve-overlapping-polygons-using-geopandas/335555#comment617478_335555) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271733/geopandas-dissolve-overlapping-polygons). The only real difference is I want to merge overlapping polygons if they are of the **same class** (an attribute).

For example, if polygons of different classes A and B overlap, they should be left as is, while if both are A or both are B, they should merged/dissolved.

```
                                            geometry  class
0  POLYGON ((233572.138 2710742.125, 233576.808 2...    A
1  POLYGON ((233539.259 2710809.727, 233543.978 2...    A
2  POLYGON ((233509.510 2710826.481, 233514.245 2...    A
3  POLYGON ((233571.415 2710766.758, 233576.102 2...    B
```

Comment: `gp_polygon.dissolve(by='attribute')`

Comment: https://geopandas.org/aggregation_with_dissolve.html

Comment: aggregation with dissolve solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the geoprocessing tool *Dissolve*. In its window, you'll be able to select which fields you want to dissolve.
Hope it helps!