# GeoPandas Overlay Intersect not intersecting some areas

Tags: python, geopandas, overlay

I have a GeoDataFrame where I want to get all intersection between the polygons comprised in it. The cope i use for this is this:

```
intersection_list = []
for index in input_gdf.index.to_list():
    # first we create the intersection between the current row and a slice of the dataframe ommiting the current row
    input_without_current_gdf = input_gdf[input_gdf.index!=index]
    current_row_gdf = input_gdf[input_gdf.index == index].drop(['area','bb_id','id'],axis=1)
    
    intersection_gdf = gpd.overlay(input_without_current_gdf,current_row_gdf,how='intersection')
    
    # then we see if there are any intersection generated 
    if intersection_gdf.shape[0] > 0:
            intersection_gdf['area'] = intersection_gdf['geometry'].area
            # and check if those intersection are larger than 0.0001         
            found_intersections = intersection_gdf.loc[intersection_gdf['area']>=0.0001]['geometry'].to_list() 
            intersection_list += found_intersections
```

This mostly works but in some cases no intersections are created even though there are clearly some for example here:

[image]

I visualized the overlapping area between area 417 and 301 by making the the layer semi transperent the darker gray area should be generated as an intersect but it isnt. Instead 613 is create as quasi empty area. Now if i do the following:

```
snapped_gdf.loc[417].geometry.intersection(snapped_gdf.loc[301].geometry)
```

the correct intersection is created

is it that area 277 is interfering and if more than two areas are overlapping an incorrect intersection is created?

[image]

Comment: your script is very complicated, see [Merging overlapping features using Geopandas?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/203044/2581) for example