# Dissolving/merging overlapping polygons in shapefile but retaining a list of original attribute values in Python/GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, dissolve, overlay

I am looking for an answer to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203902/dissolving-shapefile-but-retaining-a-list-of-original-attribute-value-in-qgis) question, for overlapping polygons, but in Python and preferably with GeoPandas.

**Background**

I have files with up to 90'000 polygons, see Tab. 1 in the Minial Working Example (MWE) attached. These polygons sometimes overlap to a large extent (see Fig. 1 in MWE attached, e.g. the polygons "One", "Two", and "Three" all overlap with each other.)

**Aim**

I would like to to get Tab. 2 in the MWE attached, i.e. merging/dissolving the polygons within **one** GeoDataFrame and keeping all polygon IDs that were merged/dissolved to create the new shapes. Shapes that do not overlap with anything should be preserved (see "No Overlap" in Tab. 2 in the MWE attached).

**What I have tried**

1. '''geopandas.overlay(gdf1, gdf1, 'how'='union')''' -> does not seem to give back merged shapes, but rather intersections, whether I set the 'how' to 'union' or 'intersection' (see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202958/merging-overlapping-features-using-geopandas) for details)
2. Using [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385782/make-a-union-of-polygons-in-geopandas-or-shapely-into-a-single-geometry) with Shapely. Seems tedious to me and I would prefer a Geopandas approach if possible. Plus I also did not find a way to do ID preservation
3. Using [this idea](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271733/geopandas-dissolve-overlapping-polygons) I retrieve the right shapes, but loose as my Polygon IDs, respectively only keep the first one

I am sure there must be an easy pythonic way, but I think I lack the terminology to find the solution.

[image: Minimal Working Example (MWE)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can groupby and specify an aggregate function for each field you want to keep.

I have four fields,

**LAN_KOD** (my group by field)

**KOMMUNKOD** which I want as a list/comma separated string

**SomeFloat** which should be summed

**geometry** which should be dissolved:

```
 import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file(r'C:\GIS\data\testdata\ak_riks_2.shp')

aggfunctions = {'KOMMUNKOD':lambda x: ','.join(str(y) for y in list(x)), #With just list as function, it would not export as a shapefile. I needed to convert it to string
                'SomeFloat':'sum', 
                'geometry': lambda x: x.unary_union}

df2 = df.groupby('LAN_KOD').agg(aggfunctions)
df3 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df2, geometry='geometry') #df2 became a pandas dataframe by the grouping
df3.to_file(r'C:\GIS\data\testdata\ak_riks_3.shp')
```

[image]